# How to send fcm notification push device to a specific device?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notifications between 2 devices. With a little research, here are my files.Here are the details of my FCMNotificationService class. Someone could help me do it. I galley over there for a long time.
Thank you!

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.proper_international.properinternationnal.miscs.Utilities;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;



public class FCMNotificationService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    // Method to send Notifications from server to client end.
    public final static String AUTH_KEY_FCM = "-----";

    public final static String API_URL_FCM = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";



    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

        // public static void pushFCMNotification(String deviceIdKey, String titre, String contenu, String userRole, String latLng, String idReserve) throws Exception {
        String authKey = AUTH_KEY_FCM; // You FCM AUTH key
        String FMCurl = API_URL_FCM;
        boolean r = false;
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(FMCurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + authKey);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("to", strings[0]);
            JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
            info.put("title", strings[1]); // Notification title
            info.put("body", strings[2]); // Notification body
            info.put("latLng", strings[3]);
            info.put("idReserve", strings[4]);
            data.put("data", info);
            data.put("notification", info);

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            r = true;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return r;
    }


}
```

But the trouble is how to find the token of the device to which I want to send the notification.

Comment: Use the FCM Instance ID of the Reciepent device to do So

Comment: you need FCM token that is generated for a user when you first install the app. Use that token to send message to particular device.

Comment: how find Reciepent device  FCM Instance ID ?

Comment: User 1:  get Token from Below 
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

User 2 : send notification to above token. Above token is the device Id created by FCM for particular device app.

Comment: I can save the token of each device in my database. Then every time I send a push notification, I get the token from the device to which I want to send the message from my database?